# Strange string length limiting (/trimming) in Vectorcast - Ada

Tags: unit-testing, ada

In the following Ada code:

```
package body TestMyApp is

  use type Base_Types.Natural16;
  use type Base_Types.Integer32;
  use type C.Strings.Chars_Ptr;
  use type C.Size_T;

  -- Error Messages length should be limited by upper bound 'Err_Msg_Max_Len'
  Err_Msg_Max_Length   : constant C.Size_T := 100;
  Glb_C_Err_Msg_String : aliased C.Char_Array := (1..(Err_Msg_Max_Length + 1) => C.nul);

  function Fixed_String_To_Chr_Ptr (Source_String        : String;
                                    Trim_For_Whitespaces : Boolean) return C.Strings.Chars_Ptr is

    Ptr               : C.Strings.Chars_Ptr := C.Strings.Null_Ptr;
    Elem_Copied_Count : C.Size_T := 0;

  begin

    -- Reset each character in Glb_C_Err_Msg_String array to nul
    Glb_C_Err_Msg_String := (1..(Err_Msg_Max_Length + 1) => C.nul);

    -- Check whether source string is of acceptable length
    if Source_String'Length <= Natural(Err_Msg_Max_Length) then

      if Trim_For_Whitespaces = True then
        -- Copy fixed string elements into char_array with
        -- source string's both side trimmed for whitespaces
        C.To_C(Item       => Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim(Source => Source_String, Side => Ada.Strings.Both),
               Target     => Glb_C_Err_Msg_String,
               Count      => Elem_Copied_Count,
               Append_Nul => True);

      else
        -- Copy fixed string elements into char_array
        C.To_C(Item       => Source_String,
               Target     => Glb_C_Err_Msg_String,
               Count      => Elem_Copied_Count,
               Append_Nul => True);
      end if;

      -- Convert char_array into char_ptr
      Ptr := C.Strings.To_Chars_Ptr(Item      => Glb_C_Err_Msg_String'Access,
                                    Nul_Check => True);

    else

      Ptr := C.Strings.Null_Ptr;

    end if;

    -- Return the char_ptr
    return Ptr;

  end Fixed_String_To_Chr_Ptr;

end TestMyApp;
```

While unit testing in ***VectorCast-Ada***, if the length of string **(Source_String)** being passed to the function **Fixed_String_To_Chr_Ptr()** is less than or equal to 100 **(Err_Msg_Max_Length)**, the function got executed correctly and the following if condition:

```
if Source_String'Length <= Natural(Err_Msg_Max_Length) then
```

got correctly evaluated to True. However strangely, if the if the length of string **(Source_String)** being passed to the function **Fixed_String_To_Chr_Ptr()** is greater than 100 **(Err_Msg_Max_Length)**, the function still **TRUE** evaluated the above-mentioned condition to true which should not happen at all since the length of the string is greater than **Err_Msg_Max_Length**. On debugging , it was observed that even if the length of string **(Source_String)** being passed to the function **Fixed_String_To_Chr_Ptr()** was greater than 100, internally the function was limiting/trimming its length to 100**(Err_Msg_Max_Length)** only.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: https://www.vectorcast.com/software-testing-products/ada-unit-testing

Comment: My guess is that you aren't testing exactly the function shown here.

Comment: Did you try to simplify the function, to figure out where the actual problem is?

Comment: I got the problem solved. See my answer below in the answers section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Vectorcast's configuration limitation for unconstrained strings defaulted to 100 size. Increasing the size resolved the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Above code is equal to following:

```
-- Check whether source string is of acceptable length
if Source_String'Length <= Natural (Err_Msg_Max_Length) then
  Trim ( ); -- to make it easier to see what is actually going on here
else -- personally, I don't see a point in this else statement
  Ptr := C.Strings.Null_Ptr;
end if;
```

So, if your Source_String is longer than Err_Msg_Max_Length Ptr is nulled (and right after that returned). Kinda odd if you ask me - I would understand trimming it to first 100 characters or something like this, but entirely dropping the message?

PS: The condition can't be true for Source_String'Length > 100... if it is then there is some odd bug - maybe in compiler. Are you sure that your 'Length > 100 ?

Comment: Yes, I am sending a string >100 in length.